# Compile a c source code from the same script

Tags: c, shell, gcc

here's my problem:

i want to write a shell script and compile a c source code from the very same script using a Pipe to the gcc compiler. Like gcc -o Name_outputfile -x c - .
I don't want to compile an external c file! The code should be in the same script. Is there a way to realize this?
Thanks!

Comment: So basically you want the compiled code in the text of the .sh file?

Comment: or like... .sh ` do script 'some c code'

Comment: if that's necessary yes, but i had in mind, that i call the script in the terminal and it would show me the compiled c code, the output. like if i compile a code in an environment.

Comment: I think the author wants to use process substitution here and send text input as a file to the gcc compiler

Comment: What's wrong with creating a temporary file with the .c suffix and compiling that, and removing it when done?

Comment: or like... .sh ` do script 'some c code' --> yes, exactly!